# How do I directly read the Nth byte from a binary file?

Tags: files-and-directories, binary

I have a very large binary file (several hundred GB) which I would like to process using *Mathematica*. I only need to process a few bytes of this file at a time, and I know in advance which bytes I would like to read.

How can I directly read the $N$th byte of this file? Functions like `OpenRead` and `BinaryReadList` seem to only be able to read from the beginning of the file.

Comment: Have a look at `StreamPosition` /  `SetStreamPosition` /  `Skip`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin `SetStreamPosition` is definitely the missing piece I was looking for! Can't believe I missed that. I'll gladly accept if you make that an answer.

Comment: I don't think Leonid is interested in writing answers that are less than 2,000 words  :-)   You may need to write it as an answer yourself so that it doesn't remain an open question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LeonidShifrin points out in the comments above, the answer is to first use `OpenRead` to open the file as an `InputStream` object, then `SetStreamPosition` to jump directly to the desired location. Then, `BinaryRead` and `BinaryReadList` can be used to read the desired bytes.

For the benefit of future readers, do note that `BinaryReadList` works with `InputStream`s, even though its `Information` only shows it working with file names. Also, `SetStreamPosition` does not use 1-based indexing like the rest of *Mathematica*; to read the 5th byte from a file, use `SetStreamPosition[stream, 4]`.

Comment: If you are reading a binary file, make sure to include `BinaryFormat -> True` in `OpenRead`